# Stress bearing suffixes in Optimality Theory

Tags: english, phonology, stress

Stress bearing suffixes in English words like *Chinese, Japanese, cigarette, fifteen* violate the *non-finality constraint*. Can anyone explain what other constraints outrank non-finality and allows the stress to fall on the last syllable?

Comment: Hammond wrote on English stress in OT in *The phonology of English:  A Prosodic Optimality-theoretic approach*, which I don't have. It's likely that he addresses this.

Comment: @user6726: [The Phonology of English : A Prosodic Optimality-Theoretic Approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=fJ6yivf6Kv0C&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). Some pages are hidden though. Also, see 'bamboo' and 'chimpanzee', they're stressed on the last syllable.

Comment: I have heard *anchoring constraint* but I don't know anything about it.